# An one-sentence proof of P ⊆ NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Recently I am reading a document [1]. In this document, Prof. Cook provides a brief proof of $\mathbf{P} \subseteq \mathbf{NP}$, which is only one sentence:

> It is trivial to show that $\mathbf{P} \subseteq \mathbf{NP}$, since for each language $L$ over $\Sigma$, if $L \in \mathbf{P}$ then we can define the polynomial-time checking relation $R \subseteq \Sigma^* \cup \Sigma^*$ by
>   $$R(w, y) \Longleftrightarrow  w \in L$$
>   for all $w, y \in \Sigma^*$.

I know the definitions of $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{NP}$, as in [1], but I still can't understand this proof. Could any one explain the proof to me? Even one sentence is good.

By the way, I think $\Sigma^* \cup \Sigma^*$ should be $\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^*$. Am I right?

#### Reference

[1] S. Cook, *The P versus NP problem*, [Online] http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/pvsnp.pdf.

Comment: yes it should be a $\times$

Comment: For almost every equivalent definitions of $P$ and $NP$, there are one line proofs for $P \subseteq NP$.

Comment: @Shreesh Could you please tell me where can I find these one-line proofs? Thank you very much.

Comment: Gary & Johnson use different definition for NP, but they use simple proof (just a mention) to show that $P \subseteq NP$, basically ignore the guess string. The certificate definition is used in Arora and Barak, they also use simple proof (just a hint) for $P \subseteq NP$, which basically ignores the certificate. Hopcroft an Ullman use different definition for NP, and they ignore non-determinism to prove $P \subseteq NP$ (just a mention in the text, that it can be done).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since L is in P, you can answer the word problem in polynomial time. To show that L is in NP as well, we need to provide a polynomial checking relation $R$ such that

$$ w\in L \Leftrightarrow \exists y.(|y|\le |w^k| \text{ and } R(w,y))$$

Now Prof. Cook says to take a very simple $R$. For every $w$ in $L$, no matter what $y\in \Sigma^*$ you take, $R(w,y)$ is true and for every $w$ not in $L$, $R(w,y)$ is false, regardless of the $y$. This is a polynomial time relation, since we can decide whether $w\in L$ or not in polynomial time (since $L \in P$), without looking at $y$ at all. And as any $y$ works, there are also some $y$ that are short enough to satisfy the length restriction in the above definition.

Answer (score 3):

$P=\{L : L\ \text{is decided by a }\mathbf{deterministic}\text{ Turing machine in polynomial time}\}$

$NP=\{L : L\text{ is decided by a (possibly non-deterministic) Turing machine in polynomial time}\}$

With these definitions, $P\subseteq NP$ is fairly obvious.

Let's call $\widetilde{NP}=\{L : \text{There is some } R \text{ so that } L_R\in P\}$ where $R\subseteq \Sigma^*\times \Sigma'^*$ and $L_R=\{u\#v : (u,v)\in R\}$. The idea here is that $u$ is the "real" input and $v$ is some extra information to help us know why we should accept $u$. For example, if the problem is $SAT$, $u$ is the formula and $v$ can be a valuation.

- $\widetilde{NP}\subseteq NP$ : Guess $v$ and then verify $u\#v$ it.
- $NP\subseteq\widetilde{NP}$ : Given $u$, $v$ will be the list transitions taken in an execution accepting $u$. To verify $u\#v$, you just need to simulate the execution of the non-deterministic machine on $u$ while using $v$ to remove non-determinism.

The proof you're referring to is just saying that $P\subseteq \widetilde{NP}$ and you don't even need $v$ because there is no non-determinism to remove.

And yes, it should be $\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^*$.

Comment: I have read your answer, thank you very much. But I can't understand the contents "$\widetilde{NP} \subseteq NP$ ... no non-determinism to remove." Could you please explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you prove that $NP \subseteq \widetile{NP}$, you take a problem $X\in NP$ and try to prove that $X \in \widetile{NP}$. Since $X$ is in $NP$, you have a non-deterministic Turing machine $M$ that decides it in polynomial time $f(n)$ for any input of size $n$. To prove it's in $\widetile{NP}$, you need to provide a *deterministic* verifier. Since you know close to nothing about $X$, it seems fairly obvious that you'll have to use $M$ to construct the verifier. But $M$ is non-deterministic and you want a determnistic verifier. You you need to "remove the non-determnism".

Comment: You do that by taking the list of transitions of the machine taken during an accepting execution as certificate. This gives you a certificate of size $P(n)$ and given the list of transition, you can simulate $M$ and just follow those transitions, so that even though $M$ is non-deterministic, you can simulate *this execution* in a deterministic way *in polynomial time*. | Now if you do the exact same thing with $P$ instead of $NP$, you don't need the certificate because $M$ is already deterministic, and so just having the input lets you infer all the transitions that were taken.

Comment: I have read your comments carefully. Thank you very much. But there are some proper nouns I still can't understand. What is the verifier? What is the _deterministic_ verifier? What is the certificate? Could you please explain them to me? Or could you please list some references so that I can understand these proper nouns from the references? Thanks in advance.